# Problema ao montar JSON com retorno do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tudo se resume a essa imagem:
[image: Dados em amarelo são exibidos através de uma conexão normal com banco de dados e o mysql, as duas primeiras linhas "se repetem" porque temos uma relação de 1 para N no banco de dados, observem que das datas estão diferentes.]

O problema está na montagem do JSON, ele não agrupa o primeiro resultado e atribui um array para as datas, como deveria ficar na imagem abaixo:
[image: Aqui é como deveria ficar, as datas agrupadas para o data, ficando num array]

Existe algum plugin no mysql ou api no php que resolva esse problema, montar o json ou Gjson a partir de um data set com relação de 1-N:
[image: Dados no SGBD quero transformar em Json agrupado/certinho]

Como fazer isso?

Segue as querys
[image: Pessoa]

[image: Inscricao]

[image: Relacionamento 1-n]

[image: Mais um complemento, código que gera a saída]

Usei o php para exemplificar o que quero, no entanto pode ver que o php não faz nada demais, só exibe o resultado da query, quero fazer a manipulação de dados na consulta, mas se não for possível, a solução em php será bem vinda. :D

Comment: Não parece errado, há 2 *Milrak* por isso o array sobre as datas. Mostre sua query.

Comment: @PapaCharlie não existe dois Milrak na table Pessoa, e sim duas inscrições de milrak na table inscrição. Realmente a query retorna duas linhas dele, no entando eu gostaria que o json agrupasse em um só objeto milrak que teria duas datas entende?

Comment: Coloca o código `php` que estás a usar.

Comment: @Edilson Eu só estou usando Mysql, funções como JSON_ARRAY e JSON_OBJECT. Não conheço solução em php para o problema. :/

Comment: Edita a pergunta, e coloca a parte do código responsável por gerar essa sequência.

Comment: @Edilson não sei para qual título mudar, então continua o mesmo e acrescentei o código que faz a sequência.

Comment: Posta o código como texto, não como imagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira simples de corrigir o problema, com a ajuda do MySQL é utilizar o [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) e depois utilizar o [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) do PHP.

Desta maneira ficaria:

```
SELECT nome, group_concat(data) FROM pessoa GROUP BY nome
```

Isso irá retornar todas as datas numa só linha, agrupado pelo nome. No final o resultado do MySQL será o seguinte, por exemplo:

```
+---------+-----------------------+
| Nome    | Data                  |
+---------+-----------------------+
| Ana     | 2016-01-01,2017-01-01 |
| Bob     | 2000-01-01            |
| Charlie | 2016-12-01,2017-01-03 |
+---------+-----------------------+
```

Dessa forma todas as datas estarão juntas, permitindo usar um `explode(',', $Data)` para quebrar as datas, que estão separadas por virgula.

---

Depois bastaria utilizar:

```
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

    $json_array[] = [
        'Nome' => $linha['nome'],
        'Data' => explode(',', $linha['data'])
    ];

}

echo json_encode($json_array);
```

Comment: desculpa minha ignorância, parece que você achou uma boa solução para o problema... Mas e quando o campo DATA for por exemplo um campo qualquer de texto, e nesse texto exista uma vírgula no meio, não teremos um pouco mais de problemas?

Comment: A documentação, do GROUP_CONCAT, especifica isto. Você pode mudar o "separador" usando `SEPARATOR str_val`. Por exemplo, `group_concat(data SEPARATOR '-- MEU SEPARADOR --')`, fazendo isso tudo ficará como `2016-01-01-- MEU SEPARADOR --2017-01-01`, você pode simplesmente fazer um `explode` do `-- MEU SEPARADOR --`.

Comment: achei essa a melhor das resposta, no entanto estou resolvendo o problema com array no php deu um trabalho danado, não está 100% mas vai sair, quando estiver pronto postarei aqui :)

Answer (score 0):

Há uma [pergunta similar no stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072832/mysql-return-multi-level-array). Para conseguir o efeito desejado você pode usar algum ORM (dos frameworks laravel, cakePHP, ... ou algo standalone como o notorm).
Ao usar algum desses vai exigir uma relativa curva de aprendizado.

O link da pergunta acima sugere duas alternativa:

fazer a consulta na primeira tabela, percorrer os resultados com um foreach, criar um novo array para cada linha retornada. Depois fazer uma segunda consulta para cada linha retornada. Um outro foreach para iterar sobre cada linha da segunda consulta e criar um novo array, para colocar dentro do da primeira consulta.

a segunda possibilidade é fazer uma unica cosulta (como você fez), e montar com o array do fetchAll a hierarquia que você quer.